# Can native code database be reverse engineered?

Tags: java, encryption, javafx, h2, native-code

I have written an application using `JavaFX` with embedded `H2 database` and compiled it into native `Windows` instructions using `Excelsior JET`. Some of the database fields must not be accessed by others. My question is should I encrypt these fields or native code instructions gives enough security?

It might seem irrational to provide application with secret data but I need to do that.

**Update**:
Any suggestions how can I protect them?

Comment: Hint: Where would you keep the encryption key?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have only one place, on the client side, somewhere inside the code.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If it's in the code, then it will be present in the object-code/byte code. If somebody is determined enough, they can find it and also reverse engineer the used algorithm.

Comment: The best you can do here is obfuscation.  Encrypting might make that obfuscation more difficult to unravel, but in the end it is the proverbial security through obscurity.  Better than nothing for minor secrets, but don't trust it to protect any valuable data.

Comment: You can use [Stringer](https://jfxstore.com/stringer/) for encrypting strings and resources. It is interoperable with Excelsior JET, as long as you avoid using features that rely on bytecode presence, such as integrity checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

Any software can be reverse engineered if you have a sufficient level of access to the platform on which it is running.  A native code database is no different.